# Instance Creation Failure in Dammam, Saudi Arabia Location on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, vps

Dammam city appears as a location option on Google Cloud Platform. However, every time I attempt to create a new instance with, it remains in a perpetual loading state and ultimately fails to create anything!
This issue only occurs with instances located in Dammam-Saudi Arabia.
How can I resolve this, please?

```
Selected Dammam, Saudi Arabia, as the location for a new instance on Google Cloud Platform.
Attempted to create a new instance.
The instance creation process began but remained in a loading state indefinitely.
```